# Merging dataframes using a correspondence table using R

Tags: r, merge, correspondence

I would like to write a function which merges two dataframes (mydf1 and mydf2) according to a correspondence table (mykeys). Consider the following example:

```
mydf1=data.frame(id1=1:5,myvar1=letters[1:5])
mydf2=data.frame(id2=LETTERS[1:5],myvar2=letters[6:10])

mykeys=data.frame(id1=1:3,id2=LETTERS[1:3])
```

The result should be

```
# id1 id2 myvar1 myvar2
# 1   A   a      f
# 2   B   b      g
# 3   C   c      h
```

Any idea?

Comment: We get the expected output based on `Reduce(merge, list(mykeys, mydf1, mydf2))` as suggested by @CathG .  Can you provide an example where it doesn't work.

Comment: My bad! It works just fine :)

Comment: Thanks, I undeleted the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `merge` after placing the datasets in a `list`.  Modified based on comments from @CathG and the edit in OP's dataset.

```
Reduce(merge, list(mykeys, mydf1, mydf2))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry, I noticed a mistake in the data I provided (`id2`). So the code you provided no longer works. My bad :)

Comment: @Clement Can you change the data in your post

Comment: then just `Reduce(merge, list(mykeys, mydf1, mydf2))` should do it, no ? Or rather `Reduce(merge, list(mykeys, mydf1, mydf2), right=TRUE)` to have the correct order